# How to optimize this T-sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a loop in this query, in the last where condition. and this
causes a severe problem to the performance of SQL.

I have no idea about how to modify it.

```
select pr.tavpun
 from mta110 pr
 where pr.taisoc = mta110.taisoc
   and pr.taitar = mta110.taitar
   and pr.taydat = mta110.taydat
   and pr.tairef = mta110.tairef
   and pr.tatind = (select max(pr2.tatind) from mta110 pr2
                    where pr2.taisoc = mta110.taisoc
                      and pr2.taitar = mta110.taitar
                      and pr2.taydat = mta110.taydat
                      and pr2.tairef = mta110.tairef
                      and pr2.tatind <= mgc100.gntind)) AS SalesPrice
```

Comment: Does that even compile with the alias for a subquery as a comparison operand? Anyway, please show the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements of the table. Show the execution plan. And add some sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with that sample data along with an explanation about the logic behind your query.

Comment: Strange looking query, did you mean to have a selfjoin which you've missed off, if not the where clauses look suspect

Comment: That query can't be valid. `mta110` has no context as an alias; so the clause `pr.taisoc = mta110.taisoc` will error with an error about the unknown object or alias `mta110`. Also, when would `taisoc ` not have a value of `taisoc` apart from when it's `NULL`? If you *are* checking for `NULL`  then you should just be using `taisoc IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: An explanation of the logic with sample data and desired results would help.  Your query is not valid because `mta110` is not defined in the outer query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query makes little sense, because `pr` is not a reasonable alias for `mta110`, and `mta110` is not recognized in the outer query.

I speculate that you have two tables, `pr` and `mta110` which are joined and you want the "most recent" row of `mta110` for each matching row.

If this interpretation is correct, then you can use `row_number()` and a proper `join`:

```
select . . .
from pr join
     (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by taisoc, taitar, taydat, tairef order by gntind desc) as seqnum
      from mta110 m
     ) m
     on pr.? = m.?
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, your assumption is exactly what it is. Thank you so much for the answer. My SQL acknowledge is too poor... Could you please help me check another query ? I couldn't understand the logic..